# How to get value from field when error from validation?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 selected dates, "start" and "end". I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 and can't upgrade. What I want to do is that when "end" date is invalid because of after_or_equal check, the error message would contain the date entered for "start". I have no idea how to get value of a different attribute not the current attribute inside the Validator::replacer. The code here just gets the value of "end" date not really "start"date which is what I really want.

```
Validator::extend('after_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
       $validator->addReplacer('after_or_equal', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($value) {
            return str_replace(':value', $value, $message);
        });
        return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) <= strtotime($value);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `Validator::extends()` second parameter is a closure, which accepts `$attribute`, `$value`, `$parameters`, and `$validator`. Here 3rd parameter is the `$parameters` array. which you can use to achieve your goal.

In the controller when you are using this validator pass the `start date`to the validator as a parameter like bellow.

```php
$startDate = request('start_date'); // or whatever the value you want.

request()->validate([
    'end_date' => ["after_or_equal:{$startDate}"],
]);
```

Now the start date has passed to the validator function in the `$parameters` array. So you can access that in the validator function.

```php
Validator::extend('after_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    // parameters is an array.
    // start date is the first element in that array.
    $startDate = $parameters[0]; 

    // Now you can do whatever you want to do with this start date.

    $validator->addReplacer('after_or_equal', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($value) {
        return str_replace(':value', $value, $message);
    });

    return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) <= strtotime($value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any of your request values using the `request()` helper.

```php
return str_replace(':value', request('start'), $message);
```